# Remove full words containing a string in Vim

Tags: string, vim, vi

I am trying to remove words from a line if they contain a specific string.  Here is an example of the text:

```
host-a, host-b, host-c+test, host-d, host-e+test
```

I want to remove anything that contains `+test`, to result with:

```
host-a, host-b, host-d
```

Likewise, I need to apply this on a line by line basis, not on all lines in the file.  It is going to be used within a macro.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you also want to remove the comma?

Comment: Yes.  Just as shown in my example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this, maybe?

```
:%s/\<[-a-z]\++test\>//gc
```

It will ask for each match if you want to replace it. Hint: `set hlsearch` will show you the matches.

If you also want to remove the comma, then:

```
%s/\(,\s\+\)\?\S\++test\>//gc
```

Comment: `-` counds as a word boundary, so you would either have to turn that off or use another solution

Comment: Ah, yes, that is true. Fixed.

Comment: The first one is working, but the second one is not.  I do need to remove the commas if present (ie, if the item is not the first in the line).

Comment: Argh! Fixed. Grouping parens need to be escaped in vim regexes.

Comment: Excellent! Works great, with one caveat.

On lines where a match is the first item, the line, after editing, starts with a comma and a space, then all of the remaining items.