# vim regex removing all words that contain a certain character that will be at the end of the word

Tags: regex, vim

I'm tryin to clean up a text document and remove certain words from every line in the document if it includes a marker (`X`).  So for the following line:

```
Adäë ee tee tdX hnX dedas ödaX.
```

Would then become:

```
Adäë ee tee dedas.
```

The characters of the alphabet are `a, e, i, o, u, ë, ä, ö, t, d, n` so `X` is not include.  Also the marker `X` will always be the last character in the word that is to be removed.  I'd tried to modified the statement from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14421942/remove-full-words-containing-a-string-in-vim) but I haven't been able to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try:

```
:%s/\s*\S*X\([aeiouëäötdn]\)\@!//g
```

It iterates over all lines and removes words that end with `X` with their leading spaces. It benefits from a negative lookahead to assert that the next letter after `X` is not from alphabet.

Answer (score 0):

VIM full substitution command is like this:

```
:%s/before/after/g
```

where

- %s is the substitution
- before is the string to match
- after is the replacement
- g is the global flag (to replace all occurrences)

For your problem, you can use

```
:%s/\s*\<\S\+X\>//g
```

where

- \s* will match all whitespace (0 or more)
- \< matches the word boundary
- \S\+ matches all non-whitespace (1 or more)
- X  for your question word should end with X
- > matches the word boundary end
- // after string is null
- g is the global replace